# Difference between UnitStep and HeavisideTheta?

Tags: functions, function-comparison

In *Mathematica*, `UnitStep[0] == 1` and `HeavisideTheta[0]` remains unevaluated. In addition, `D[UnitStep[x], x]` is `0` if `x != 0` and `Indeterminate` if `x == 0`, whereas `D[HeavisideTheta[x],x] = DiracDelta[x]`.

It seems to me that `UnitStep` is the idealization of a leading edge of a perfect pulse, whereas `HeavisideTheta[x]` is like an ideal Fourier Transform of the ideal `UnitStep[x]` function. Is this a good way to distinguish between the two, and are there any other significant programming or mathematical distinctions between the two functions?

Thanks.

Comment: As a rough rule of thumb: use `HeavisideTheta[]` for *symbolic* calculations, and `UnitStep[]` for numerical calculations.

Comment: Thanks @J.M. I'll keep that in mind. Kudos.

Comment: Just to expand on @J.M.'s "`UnitStep` for numeric" comment. Doing `list = RandomReal[1, 10^6]; AbsoluteTiming[UnitStep[list];] AbsoluteTiming[HeavisideTheta[list];]`. `UnitStep` comes out as two orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: That's an interesting consideration @aardvark2012, thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 1):

HeavisideTheta is a distribution. Distributions  are the kernels of linear maps by complete definite integrals over a domain for a special class of functions to complex numbers.

As such, Theta is the primitive of Delta in the following sense

```
Integrate[f[x] HeavisideTheta'[x],x\[Element] domain]  == 
-     Integrate[f'[x] HeavisideTheta[x],x\[Element] domain]  ==
       -f[+boundary] + f[0]
```

This is valid only if f, f' etc go to zero sufficently fast so that integration by parts has boundary values zero. Products of Theta and other functions, that do not decay at inifinity on the real line, make no sense. Especially, the product of distributions make no sense in general.

UnitStep on the contrary is only a piecewise continuous point-to-point function with no regard to any type of function spaces with an integrability condition, that yields the existence of Fourier transforms back and forth.

Comment: See, for example, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) for a more or less accurate proof. The integrals written down by you are not  OK .