# UnitStep vs HeavisideTheta; KroneckerDelta vs DiscreteDelta

Tags: functions, piecewise

What are the differences between these pairs of functions? In many cases, they seem to act the same. For example, both `DiscreteDelta` and `KroneckerDelta` are defined to be 1 when the argument is 0 and zero otherwise. Both exhibit the "sifting" property:

```
{Sum[KroneckerDelta[a, 3] f[a], {a, Infinity}], 
    Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - 3] f[a], {a, Infinity}]}
{f[3],f[3]}
```

Similarly, both `UnitStep` and `HeavisideTheta` plot the same, and act the same in many situations -- you can simply replace one with the other in many of the examples in the Help files, for instance:

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x Cos[x]], {x, -5, 5}]
```

and

```
Integrate[UnitStep[x Cos[x]], {x, -5, 5}]
```

return the same thing. Yet they are not identical. Consider:

```
D[HeavisideTheta[t], t]
```

which returns `DiracDelta[t]` vs.

```
D[UnitStep[t], t]
```

[image]

The question is how to understand the differences in these functions, how to know what situations would call for `HeavisideTheta` vs `DiracDelta` and when to use `KroneckerDelta` instead of `DiscreteDelta`. Is there an underlying pattern?

Comment: Related: [difference-between-unitstep-and-heavisidetheta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156138/difference-between-unitstep-and-heavisidetheta).

Comment: The admonition I gave in the comments of the question @aardvark linked to still very much apply.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that UnitStep is defined at the discontinuity and HeavisideTheta is not.

```
y[x_] = UnitStep[x];

y[0]
(* 1 *)

y1[x_] = HeavisideTheta[x];


y1[0]
(* HeavisideTheta[0] *)
```

According to the Help pages, DiscreteDelta[n1,n2...] is 1 if all the n's are 0, and KroneckerDelta[n1,n2...] is 1 of all the n's are equal.