# Why does HeavisideTheta not have an implicit piecewise expansion?

Tags: piecewise, discontinuity, internals

The [Heaviside step function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) implicitly expands to a piecewise function:

```
UnitStep[t - 3] // PiecewiseExpand
```

$$ \begin{cases}  1 & t\geq 3 \\ 0 & \text{True} \\ \end{cases} $$

But the [Heaviside step with strict inequalities](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html) does not have an implicit expansion:

```
HeavisideTheta[t - 3] // PiecewiseExpand
```

$$ \theta (t-3) $$

and the expansion must be given explicitly (Solution from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47856/72415)):

```
% /. {
   HeavisideTheta[x_] :> Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {0, x < 0}}]
} // PiecewiseExpand
```

$$ \begin{cases} 1 & t>3 \\ 0 & \text{True} \\ \end{cases} $$

Is this just an oversight in the implementation or is there a more nuanced distinction?

Related:

[Converting HeavisideTheta[]s and Sign[]s functions to a single Piecewise[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47843/converting-heavisidethetas-and-signs-functions-to-a-single-piecewise)

[UnitStep vs HeavisideTheta; KroneckerDelta vs DiscreteDelta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159865/unitstep-vs-heavisidetheta-kroneckerdelta-vs-discretedelta?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `D[HeavisideTheta[x], x]` evaluates to `DiracDelta[x]`. If `HeavisideTheta` converted to a `Piecewise` expression this relation to `DiracDelta` would be obscured.

Comment: @Bob I saw that you converted your answer into a comment. I think it’s insightful enough to stand as an answer though. Would you consider undeleting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`D[HeavisideTheta[x], x]` evaluates to `DiracDelta[x]`. If `HeavisideTheta` converted to a `Piecewise` expression this relation to `DiracDelta` would be obscured.

Comment: Thank you! (+1)