# How to plot a piece-wise function like this: f[x]=1 when -1<=x<=1, and f[x]=0 when x>1 or x<-1

Tags: plotting, functions, piecewise

I want to plot a piece-wise function like this:

`f[x]=1` when `-1<=x<=1`, and `f[x]=0` when `x>1` or `x<-1`

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far? Have you already looked at `Piecewise` and `Plot`?

Comment: You can use UnitBox[x/2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big advantage of Mathematica is that you can almost literally write your thoughts

```
f[x_ /; -1 <= x <= 1] := 1
f[x_ /; x > 1] := 0
f[x_ /; x < -1] := 0
```

After defining your function, you can plot or do whatever with it

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

You can also

- combine the conditions, for instance
  `f[x_ /; x < -1||x > 1] := 0`
- use `Piecewise`
- use `UnitBox[x/2]`
- use `Boole`
- use `If`
- a combination of `UnitStep`
- a combination of `HeavisideTheta`

Each has own advantages, and they differ slightly in treating the discontinuity.

Comment: Since you mentioned all of these, you might elaborate a bit on their differences. There's also this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156138/12